# Optical drive, external floppy and external hard drive are not appearing in the file manager

Tags: nautilus

I have just upgraded Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.10. I first upgraded to 13.04, then to 13.10. When I click on *Files*, then click on *Computer*, my optical drives, hard drive, and external drive do not appear in the file manager window. Is there a way to fix this? I hope I phrased this question better this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I click on files, then click on computer my optical drives, hard drive, and external drive do not appear...

In Nautilus file manager, your devices appear in *Files* -> *Devices* heading. In Ubuntu 13.10, *Computer* is a device entry that appears under the *Devices* heading along with other devices such as your external hard drive, external floppy (if there is a floppy disk in it), etc. The **Devices** heading is the second heading in the **Places** pane on the left side of Nautilus (*Files* -> *View* -> *Sidebar* -> *Places*).